# SAPUI5 - Storing Images?

Tags: image, sapui5, offline

I have a SAPUI5 application running in SAP Cloud Platform.

This is also deployed as an offline mobile app.

It'll be storing a LOT of images, (e.g. photo from the camera etc).

My initial thought was to store them separately, on our servers, instead of holding the images in the online/offline DB.

However, as an offline user, who could be taking pictures while offline, we need to have some method of synching back to the online DB...

if that's the case are we forced into storing the images in the SAP DB, so that the online/offline DBs can be synched?

Comment: How are you deploying it as a mobile app? Is it a hybrid app with Cordova / Kapsel? Or is it with the so called SAP Mobile Services?

Comment: It's built in SCP Fiori Mobile which uses kapsel/cordova